# Filling a NA-Vector multiple times with the same vector [day number of the year]

Tags: r, vector, time-series, rep

I have the following solution, which works, but creates an error message.

```
      day.number.year <- (1:33810)*NA
      day.number.year[] <- rep(seq(1,360, by = 1), times = 94)

Warning message:
In day.number.year[] <- rep(seq(1, 360, by = 1), times = 94) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is there a more elegant option? Basically, the whole NA-Vector should get filled and everything, which extents the vector, should get cut off.

I have to create a vector with the day number of the year for a timespan (2005-2099), but for one year, there is no data for December (2099). Thats why one year has only 330 days. My data is based on a 360 day calendar.

Comment: A warning message is not an error message. The first line should probably be `day.number.year <- rep(NA, 33810)` and the second line does not seem necessary. I think you can do this in a single line with the `length.out` argument: `day.number.year <- rep(1:360, length.out=33810)`.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Originally, I used length.out, but I must have made a mistake in the end, because it didn't work for me. I will edit my message. Your solution works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by Imo:

```
day.number.year <- rep(1:360, length.out=33810)
```